# asp.net web forms application for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

hi there guys I would like to make a server side, database driven application with asp.net but would like to do it for wordpress. since wordpress is purely php is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nopes you can't as WordPress is in PHP, .net and php are of different platform.

Probably you can try out something to convert .net code in php, play around with dotnetnuke.